# Is exporting your wordpress website and adding it to this filezilla server the same as creating a local copy of your website

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, filezilla

I wanted to find out if I download/export my wordpress website and upload it to my filezilla server, is that the same thing as creating a local copy? Also is that what MAMP is used for?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. You also have to create database for the local copy and set the database connections in wp-config.php. WordPress stores file in wp-content folder and used database for storing page data, post data, comments, etc.

You should first understand about how to Install WordPress - [Click here](http://yogihosting.com/how-to-install-wordpress/).

MAMP is used to run WordPress in Local PC. There is also XAMPP which is similar to MAMP. If you are WordPress developer you can use either XAMPP or MAMP to create WordPress Websites.